# Insert after firstchild div in pure JS

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid

I am using pure JS to append a HTML string after a div that has been found by `getElementById`. This is working correctly but I would now like to append after the first child of the found element.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7gL3933/)

**HTML**

First Div
Div I want to append to
Other div...

(the second and third divs have no id or class)

**JS**

```
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

var element1 = document.createElement("div");
element1.innerHTML = 'Text to append';
var div1 = document.getElementById('first-div');
insertAfter(div1, element1);
```

Current result is:

> First Div
>   Div I want to append to
>   Other div...
>   Text to append

I am trying to achieve this:

> First Div
>   Div I want to append to
>   Text to append
>   Other div...

I have tried

```
var div1 = document.getElementById('first-div').firstchild;
```

but this is not working

Comment: This may be a typo, but from the example you've given, the div you want to append to is not the child of the first div, but rather a sibling...

Comment: @MichaelBeeson You're quite right, it is a typo. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, your example suggests the div you want to append to is not the child, but rather the sibling of "first-div". It should look like

```
<div id="first-child">
    <div>Div I want to append to</div>
</div>
```

Then the first child of the parent div can be found with

```
var div2 = div1.children[0];
```

I fiddled with your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/01qrmj36/

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the referenceNode from the insertBefore call in your insertAfter example it should behave how you want it to, eg:

```
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode);
}

var element1 = document.createElement("div");
element1.innerHTML = 'Text to append';
var div1 = document.getElementById('first-div');
insertAfter(div1, element1);
```

Omitting the referenceNode from insertBefore defaults to inserting the new node at the end of the list of child nodes, see more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).